# get breakpoint 1.1 error runtime in swift

Tags: swift

I build a UIPickerView with four components and I want to assign each component and row that selected to my vars but i get Thread 1:breakpoint 1.1 runtime error in this function

```
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    println("jjjj")
    println(component)
    switch(component){
    case 0:
        person = persons [component][row]
    case 1:
        year = persons [component][row]
    case 2:
        month = persons [component][row]
    case 3:
        day = persons [component][row]
    default : break

    }
}
```

and my complete code is

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class VariziJadidController: UIViewController,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var mablagh: UITextField!
var person = ""
var year = ""
var month = ""
var day = ""

var persons = [
["احمد","حسین","حمید","مهدی","رضا"]
,["1394" , "1395" , "1396" , "1397" , "1398" , "1399" , "1400"]
,["فروردین","اردیبهشت","خرداد","تیر","مرداد","شهریور","مهر","آبان","آذر","دی","بهمن","اسفند"]
,["31" , "30" , "29" , "28" , "27" , "26" , "25" , "24" , "23" , "22" , "21" , "20" , "19" , "18", "17" , "16" , "15" , "14" , "13" , "12" , "11" , "10" , "9" , "8" , "7" ,"6" , "5" , "4" , "3" , "2" , "1"]
]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
   return persons.count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return persons [component].count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String!{
    return persons [component][row]
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
    println("jjjj")
    println(component)
    switch(component){
    case 0:
        person = persons [component][row]
    case 1:
        year = persons [component][row]
    case 2:
        month = persons [component][row]
    case 3:
        day = persons [component][row]
    default : break

    }
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var mojodiTemp : MojoodiSandoghController = segue.destinationViewController as MojoodiSandoghController
    mojodiTemp.tempMojoodi = mablagh.text!
    var HesabeHarFard : SoratHesabeAaza = segue.destinationViewController as SoratHesabeAaza
    HesabeHarFard.person.text = person
    HesabeHarFard.year.text = year
    HesabeHarFard.month.text = month
    HesabeHarFard.day.text = day
}
```

}

how can I solve that ?

Comment: what line in particular is throwing the error?

Comment: And what is printing out?

Comment: @tbondwilkinson print out (lldb) and in this line " println("jjjj") "

Comment: did you accidentally set a breakpoint? check the left margin of your code in Xcode

Comment: Change it to `print` rather than `println`?  `println` was deprecated in swift 2.0